# solve pd.read_sql: day is out of range for month

Tags: pandas, postgresql, psycopg2, date-parsing

I am reading stuff from a postgresql database.

```
query='SELECT * FROM a_table'
conn = psycopg2.connect(*args,**kwargs)
df=pd.read_sql(query,con=conn)
```

I get `day is out of range for month`

I have tried, the following that in my understanding would disable date parsing. However, I still get same error...
How to run the query and deal with date errors in python-script space?

```
  df=pd.read_sql(query,con=conn,parse_dates=[])
```

Comment: And you really expect an answer with this lack of information. At a minimum the following needs to be added to question 1) The data type of the 'date' column 2) What is returned by `show datestyle ;` in the command line client `psql` 3) An example of the data returned by `select date_col from a_table` in `psql`?

Comment: Hi Adrian. I will try to collect the information you request.  Regarding 2: where should I run 'show datestyle ;'?

Comment: As mentioned in `psql`.

Comment: If you find what I think you will,  search for `dayfirst` here [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html?highlight=dayfirst).